# Offset curves based on width of profile curve like a multi-lane road? (Geometry Nodes)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm looking to setup a Road with geometry nodes and trying to work out if there's a way to offset more curves and/or subdivide based on the width of my profile curve?

I've tried to explain it in the image below but basically I'm trying to make it so that the wider the road gets the more lanes it will automatically add in

So far I can only think to do something like this and select the subdivided edge loops, but I'm not sure how I would subdivide it based on length:
[How do you select an edge loop in geometry nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258817/how-do-you-select-an-edge-loop-in-geometry-nodes)

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure what you want to achieve, but is it this?

[image]

the downside here is that you have to care about your angles of your road. They shouldn't be too sharp.

and here based on width:

[image]

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is basically a procedural Highway Road setup so you can think of the overall width as the road and then the subdivided lines within it as the lanes (only along the longer dimension though which is why I was looking for a way to select only 1 set of uv edge loops, if that's possible? so I can then run mesh lines along these as lanes like in this image: https://cdn1.epicgames.com/ue/product/Featured/Highwaygenerator_featured-894x488-f695a0e3804d4c8c0e6379bf7de0867e.png

For your above would there be a way to use the realise instances node instead?
Thx Chris